# VSCode Modifying and Overwriting CSS Attributes with css.customData

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create an extension to add and modify some of the default css attributes VSCode knows.

For that reason, I use the [`contributes.css.customData`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/main/docs/customData.md) endpoint. I successfully created a new extension and added some new css attributes.

My problem now is that I need to overwrite some default attributes like `border`. If I try to do that, VSCode still shows me the default description and values for `border`.

I tried adding the `border` attribute in my `.css-data.json`-file, but it still shows me the default description and hints for the `border` attribute.

Is there a way, without creating a completely new language-feature, to overwrite the standard CSS attributes?

EDIT:

I was asked for a minimal sample code. I just created a standard typescript extension and in `package.json` I added:

```json
{
    ...
    "contributes": {
        "css": {
            "customData": [
                "./css-data/program_name.css-data.json"
            ]
        }
    ...
}
```

In the corresponding `program_name.css-data.json` I added:

```json
{
    "version": 1.1,
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "border",
            "description": "this should be shown if a border attribute is used"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I now run the plugin, it shows me the standard description for border.

If I rename the property name to e.g. "myborder", it works for that attribute.